# Algorithmic complexity of Data.Hashtable

Tags: haskell, data-structures, hashtable, time-complexity

I am attempting to write a function that utilizes hashes (for an implementation of A*).

After a little bit of research, I have found that the defacto standard is `Data.Map`.

However, when reading the API documentation, I found that: `O(log n). Find the value at a key.`

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html

In fact the documentation generally suggests big O times significantly inferior to the O(1) of a standard Hash.

So then I found `Data.HashTable`.
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.2/docs/Data-HashTable.html
This documentation does not mention big O directly, leading me to believe that it probably fulfills my expectations.

I have several questions:
1) Is that correct? Is O(lookupInDataHashTable) = O(1)?
2) Why would I ever want to use `Data.Map` given its inefficiency?
3) Is there a better library for my data structure needs?

Comment: In practice you should benchmark O(1) vs O(log n) algorithms (the former may have a bigger constant), `Data.Map` or `Data.IntMap` could be a good choice. If you wish `Data.HashTable` check https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables In general I think is most important the final memory usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Why would I ever want to use Data.Map given its inefficiency?

It may not be efficient, but it supports any type of key with an Ord instance, even those cannot be hashed to an integer.

> > Is O(lookupInDataHashTable) = O(1)?

Generally yes. The workflow of "lookupInDataHashTable" and the corressponding performance in big-O notation is:

1. Hash the key. for integer: O(1), for string: O(length of string)
2. Access an IOArray with the hash, get a list containing all the key-value pairs which have the same hash. O(1)
3. Look up the key in the list. O(length of the list)

So unless you have very long strings as keys, the lookup function gurantees O(1) performance.

> > Is there a better library for my data structure needs?

It depends on the type of your key. For distinct integers Data.IntMap bests, for other hash-able types Data.HashMap shows decent performance, otherwise you have no choice but Data.Map.

Comment: My key is of type String

Comment: @AbrahamP You may want to consider a (path-compressed) trie in that case.

Comment: @AbrahamP, how long are your keys? That really does make a difference. Also, you should see if hash maps, trie variants, etc., are fast enough before you abandon purity and its advantages to use hash tables.

Answer (score 6):

`Data.HashTable` has been deprecated and you won't find it in current [`base`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/index.html).

It was deprecated because it performed poorly in comparison to [`hashtables`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables).

However, `hashtables` and `Data.HashTable` are both mutable implementations, while [`Data.Map`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.5.6.2/Data-Map.html) and [`Data.HashMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) are immutable.

Mutable hashmaps in Haskell are similar to the array-of-buckets or open addressing solutions in other languages. Immutable maps are based on trees or tries. In general, immutable associative containers can't be implemented with O(1) modification.

So why use immutable maps?

First, the API is much more convenient in Haskell. We can't use use mutable maps in pure functions, only in IO or ST actions.

Second, immutable maps can be safely shared between threads, which is often a crucial feature.

Third, in practice, performance difference between mutable and immutable maps can be insignificant, i. e. it doesn't noticeably impact overall program performance. O(log n) is also bounded by the available memory, so we don't get spectacular asymptotic differences compared to O(1). In particular, `Data.HashMap` uses a 16-branching trie, so trie depth can't realistically be more than 6 or 7.

Fourth, immutable maps can be just plain faster for reasons that I don't fully understand (more optimized libraries? better optimization from GHC?); I have tried a couple of times to replace `Data.HashMap` with mutable maps from `hashtables`, but the performance was always a bit worse afterwards.

Comment: Have both large and small mutable maps generally performed worse for you?

Comment: Large mutable maps performed worse. In particular, the commented-out `trieToNode` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/packed-dawg-0.2.0.8/docs/src/Data-DAWG-Packed.html#pack) performed significantly worse for maps with 300k-500k elements.